# Absolutely continuous invariant measures for a minimal flow

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Fix $(X, g)$ to be some compact Riemannian manifold and $V \in \Gamma(TX)$ a smooth, non-vanishing vector field. Suppose the flow is *minimal*, i.e. every orbit is dense in $X$, and *volume-preserving*.

Suppose there exists a measure $\sigma$ that is both invariant under the flow of $V$ and absolutely continuous with respect to the Riemannian volume measure. In other words, it is given by integration against $f \text{dvol}_g$ for $f \in L^1(X)$.

If $f$ is not merely $L^1$ but continuous, then our topological assumptions imply immediately that $f$ is constant, so actually any invariant measures are a constant multiple of the volume measure (the minimality precludes the existence of any singular invariant measures).

Can we construct an example such that $f$ is *not* constant almost everywhere?

Comment: I don't think the minimality precludes the existence of singular invariant measures. You have the celebrated Furstenber's example, in Furstenberg's paper "Strict erogidicity and transformations of the torus", which is a minimal smooth area-preserving diffeomorphism in the 2-torus and is not uniquely ergodic. In that example every ergodic measure is singular respect to Lebesgue.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. The singular invariant measures could be supported on a Lebesgue measure zero, yet dense subset. I did read a bit about the Furstenberg example, but it's explicitly noted that the transformation here is not isotopic to the identity - in particular it can't arise from a flow like in my question.

Comment: Furstenberg's example is indeed isotopic to the identity. However, that is not the point. The suspension flow of any minimal diffeomorphism produces a minimal flow and if the diffeomorphism preserves a smooth volume form (in this case an area form), the suspended flow preserves one as well. So, one can produce such a flow from Furstenberg's example.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer to your question is "yes", and in fact,
Furstenberg's example can be used to construct such an example.

The idea of Furstenberg's construction in the paper [Strict Ergodicity and Transformation of the Torus](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372899?origin=crossref&seq=1) consists in finding an
irrational number $\alpha$ and a $\phi\in
C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^1,\mathbb{R})$ with $\int\phi(x) d\mathrm{Leb}(x) = 0$ such that there is a
measurable $L^1$ function $u\colon \mathbb{T}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$\phi(x) = u(x+\alpha) - u(x)$ for Lebesgue a.e. $x\in\mathbb{T}$, but
there is no continuous function $u$ satisfying this property.

Then, the diffeomorphism $g : \mathbb{T}^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto
(x+\alpha,y+\phi(x))$ is minimal, preserves the Lebesgue measure of
$\mathbb{T}^2$, but this is not an ergodic measure. In fact, the map
$h : (x,y)\mapsto (x,y+u(x))$ leaves invariant the Lebesgue measure of
$\mathbb{T}^2$ and $g\circ h = h \circ k$, where $k : (x,y)\mapsto
(x+\alpha, y)$; and Lebesgue is clearly not ergodic for $k$.

However, there are infinitely many $k$-invariant measures which are
absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue. To see this, one can
consider for instance a non trivial interval $I\subset\mathbb{T}$
(i.e. $I$ and its complement contain more than one point), and
define the measure $\mu:= \mathrm{Leb} \otimes
\frac{1}{\mathrm{Leb}(I)}\mathrm{Leb}\big|_I$. Then, since $h$
preserves Lebesgue, we conclude that $h_*\mu$ is $g$ invariant, is
absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue and is different from
Lebesgue.